# How to get value from dictionary in list of tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below and I want to store the values meaning 1, 1 in a list.

```
sc_dict=[('n', {'rh': 1}), ('n', {'rhe': 1}), ('nc', {'rhex': 1})]
```

I want an array `[1,1,1]`.

This is my code:

```
dict_part = [sc[1] for sc in sc_dict]

print(dict_part[1])

L1=[year for (title, year) in (sorted(dict_part.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))]
print(L1)
```

Comment: If one of the below solutions solved your problem, please consider accepting (green tick on left), or feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [v for t1, t2 in sc_dict for k, v in t2.items()]
[1, 1, 1]
```

`t1` and `t2` being respectively the first and second item of each tuple, and `k`, `v` the key-value pairs in the dict `t2`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I add 0 for the values that are not in sc_dict. Basically I have two dictionary like this but sc_dict_1=[('n', {'rh': 1}), ('n', {'rhe': 1}), ('nc', {'rhex': 1})] and sc_dict2=[('n', {'hm': 1}), ('n', {'rhe': 1}), ('nc', {'rhex': 1})] for example I want array one [0, 1, 1, 1] because hm from array 2 does not exist in array 1

Comment: @sarajones: which values? please add an example in your original question

Comment: sorry!Please look at  sc_dict2. it has ('n', {'hm': 1}) which is not present in sc_dict_1. So I want to add 0 in the results array for  ('n', {'hm': 1}) and have final result like: [0, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: your example is very ambiguous. I assume you want to work with items in the same place in the two arrays, i.e. compare first item of sc_dict1 with first item of sc_dict2, then compare second item of sc_dict1 with second item of sc_dict2, and so on... in that case consider using `zip(sc_dict_1, sc_dict2)` so that you have a single zipped array, in that case the first item would be `(('n', {'rh': 1}), ('n', {'hm': 1}))`. now, from this item, how do you compute the `0`/`1` values?

Comment: No, basically what I want is two arrays: array_sc_dict_1=[0,1,1,1] and array_sc_dict2=[0,1,1,1]. because I want to use elucidance distance the length of my two arrays should be the same?

Comment: in your example, the input array has 3 items, the resulting array has 4 0/1 values. it's not clear what you want to compute. you'd better off asking a new question explaining what you are trying to compute and provide some clear and unambiguous example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpacking:

```
sc_dict=[('n', {'rh': 1}), ('n', {'rhe': 1}), ('nc', {'rhex': 1})]
new_data = [list(b.values())[0] for _, b in sc_dict]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

It can become slightly cleaner with one additional step:

```
d = [(a, b.items()) for a, b in sc_dict]
new_data = [i for _, [(c, i)] in d]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` to retrieve the first value of your dictionary as part of a list comprehension.

This works since your dictionaries have length 1.

```
sc_dict=[('n', {'rh': 1}), ('n', {'rhe': 1}), ('nc', {'rhex': 1})]

res = [next(iter(i[1].values())) for i in sc_dict]

# [1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the simple way like below:

```
sc_dict=[('n', {'rh': 1}), ('n', {'rhe': 1}), ('nc', {'rhex': 1})]
l = []
for i in range(len(sc_dict)):
    l.extend(sc_dict[i][1].values())
print l
```

The output `l` would be `[1, 1, 1]`